# Как сделать 3D объект прозрачным в PascalAbc.NET в библиотеке Graph3D?

Tags: графика, pascalabc.net, прозрачность

Хочу добавить прозрачности объекту. Пытался играться с разными функциями класса Materials: Diffuse, Specular, Emissive. Передавал им в качестве параметра [ARGB](https://pascalabc.net/downloads/pabcnethelp/index.htm?page=LangGuide/index_lang_guide.html) функцию с параметром прозрачности отличным от 255. Но прозрачность не появляется. Возможно конечно она не реализована в Graph3D. Но хотелось бы узнать наверняка.

Comment: Мои студенты говорят, что не реализована: они делали псевдопрозрачность, отрисовывая объект и удаляя его.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, ого, каждый раз отрисовывать, а потом стирать и так по кругу. Офигеть какая нагрузка на проц.